# Download is disallowed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to save the html to a file by creating a blob and then downloading/saving it.

In particular I would like to do this on the following website: https://news.yahoo.com/explainer-house-representatives-elects-speaker-135629660.html

When I run the following code (in the chrome console of the dev tools):

```
let iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
let blob = new Blob([new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)], {type: "html/text"});
let file_name = "yahoo-dwnld.html";

let saver = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
let blobURL = saver.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob), body = document.body;
saver.download = file_name;

body.appendChild(saver);
saver.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
body.removeChild(saver);
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

I get the following error message:

> Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the
> download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more
> details.

First googling this error message let me to some solutions that said this is a problem with the iframes.

It also puzzles me that this error message is still referring to a frame that is sandboxed. However, I cannot locate this frame inside my html (I already removed all iframes) or better said: I do not know which element of the DOM I should modify by setting this sandbox attribute `allow-downloads`.

But since I removed them I do not understand why this still is a problem in my case.

Comment: I don't know where or how you implemented this code, but I suspect it prevents a page from automatically starting a download. Have you tried downloading when you click a button?

Comment: You can run this code in the console of the dev tools yourself. It actually works fine on other websites.

Comment: That won't guarantee the same outcome. The browser's devtools doesn't have the same security rules as a web page.